# You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-console

In my Xamarin.Forms project, I Archive for Publishing an .aab file but when I try to upload it on Google Play Console for internal testing I get the error message:

> You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security
> reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in
> Google Play

I tried adding this to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:debuggable="false"
```

Comment: check Android --> Build in the project properties

Comment: I see `Enable developer instrumentation` but it won't let me uncheck it.

Comment: have you selected a Release config?

Comment: Yes I did. It does not let me uncheck it for Debug config either.

Comment: Did you try to add the following code `#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif` in to the AssemblyInfo.cs file?